# Groupby() function of pandas working incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

When I call my data frame

```
 third_class.head()
```

This is how it looks:

```
  Pclass     Fare    Survived    Fare Kind  Counts
0    3      7.2500      0         Lowest     1
2    3      7.9250      1          Low       1
4    3      8.0500      0          Low       1
5    3      8.4583      0         Medium     1
7    3     21.0750      0          high      1
```

I wanted to group my data according to Survived and Fare Kind, I used the following code

```
 third_class_grouped =third_class.groupby(["Survived","Fare Kind"], as_index=False)["Counts"].sum()
```

This is the output I'm getting for

```
third_class_grouped.head()

                        Survived    Fare Kind   Counts
 Survived   Fare Kind           
     0        Lowest       NaN        NaN        NaN
               Low         NaN        NaN        NaN
              Medium       NaN        NaN        NaN
               high        NaN        NaN        NaN
     1        Lowest       NaN        NaN        NaN
```

How do I rectify my code to get the sums in place of NaN's in Counts columns and force the Survived and Fare kind out of index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
 sums = third_class.groupby(["Survived","Fare Kind"]).sum()
 sums['Counts'].reset_index()
```

I find that just summing everything and then selecting the aggregation after is easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and precise reply, that did rectify the error